# Distinct is not working in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, distinct

```
Select Distinct _Ad.ad_id,_Ad.Ad_Name,ID.Image_Path,VM.year,VD.Vehicle_Transformation,VD.Vehicle_Fuel_Type,VD.Vehicle_Millege
from _Ad 
inner join _Image_Details ID 
on ID.ad_id = _Ad.ad_id
inner join _Vehicle_Model VM
on VM.vehicle_model_id = _AD.vehicle_model_id
inner join _Vehicle_Details VD
on _ad.ad_id=VD.ad_id
inner join _Vehicle_Make VMA
on VM.vehicle_make_id=VMA.vehicle_make_id
where
VMA.Vehicle_Make='' OR
VM.Vehicle_Model='' OR
VD.Vehicle_Fuel_Type='' OR
VD.Vehicle_Seats='' OR
_Ad.price>'0' OR _Ad.price<'8888888'
```

i am using this query but its showing 4 records not 1. I need only single record across 1 ad_id. Kindly help. [image]

Comment: well., it does because the rows are different

Comment: can you please help me how to get single record?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea which row you want, so no, I can't actually help

Comment: Take out image path from the sql query. you will get two rows

Comment: I need one record across 1 ad_id

Comment: Pretend you're not writing SQL for a minute.  How do you, as a human, decide which row of data you want?

Comment: Right... like which `image_path` would you want to display for that 1 `ad_id`? How would you determine that as a human?

Comment: Do a `MIN` or `MAX(ID.Image_Path)` and `GROUP BY`all other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`, try using `SELECT TOP 1`. So your code would look like

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.ad_id,
    a.Ad_Name, 
    b.Image_Path, 
    c.year,
    d.Vehicle_Transformation,
    d.Vehicle_Fuel_Type,
    d.Vehicle_Millege
FROM _Ad a, _Image_Details b, 
    _Vehicle_Model c, 
    _Vehicle_Details d, 
    _Vehicle_Make e
WHERE b.ad_id = a.ad_id 
    AND c.vehicle_model_id = a.vehicle_model_id 
    AND a.ad_id = d.ad_id 
    AND c.vehicle_make_id = e.vehicle_make_id
    e.Vehicle_Make='' OR
    c.Vehicle_Model='' OR
    d.Vehicle_Fuel_Type='' OR
    d.Vehicle_Seats='' OR
    a.price>'0' OR a.price<'8888888'
```

If you want one of each `a.ad_id` as you say, you will need to get rid of the `b.Image_Path`. So it would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ad_id,
        a.Ad_Name, 
        c.year,
        d.Vehicle_Transformation,
        d.Vehicle_Fuel_Type,
        d.Vehicle_Millege
    FROM _Ad a, _Image_Details b, 
        _Vehicle_Model c, 
        _Vehicle_Details d, 
        _Vehicle_Make e
    WHERE b.ad_id = a.ad_id 
        AND c.vehicle_model_id = a.vehicle_model_id 
        AND a.ad_id = d.ad_id 
        AND c.vehicle_make_id = e.vehicle_make_id
        e.Vehicle_Make='' OR
        c.Vehicle_Model='' OR
        d.Vehicle_Fuel_Type='' OR
        d.Vehicle_Seats='' OR
        a.price>'0' OR a.price<'8888888'
```

Comment: its giving only single record. I need 1 record across each ad_id.

Comment: Well like others have commented, and I have also in my answer, get rid of the `Image_Path` and you will get that with your original query

Comment: I updated my answer. It should give you what you need except it won't show the column for `Image_Path`